# Conditional formula that recolors names if multiple in the same list match multiple in a separate list, but only if multiple exist

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This has stumped me..
[example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jGSm83hQXhWqZDFvtL2l7s-_jfHLowd34rQZJN-0PVA/edit?usp=sharing)
I'm looking for a conditional formula that will flag/recolor names if multiple names are used from a select column "database" in a sort of "roster" or schedule format.

You will see on sheet 2 that there are lists of names in columns.  In sheet 1, there are "groups" of names.  I want it to recolor the names if multiple people from the same column on sheet 2 are in the same "group" on sheet 1.  It should only recolor them if 2+ names from the same column are in the same group.  1 name from a column is fine.
The use case is so if I schedule groups of individuals that overlap certain skill sets, I can notice that I've sort of double booked people who share a similar skill set and can better be used in a group where that area is lacking.

I use a formula to match a name 1 to 1, but I haven't figured out a way to modify it for this specific case (taken from the actual sheet).  This is also limited by being used in a range of a singular column, so this has to be applied to every single column with different ranges.  Tried different versions of an arrayformula I found in other posts but obviously so far have been unsuccessful.

```
=match(I42,indirect("staff!N10:N32"),0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WOCBmsTI7VzNqS5v6tD7mCwWi7YUtx_P6fNleTAxsUg/edit?usp=sharing)

1. Use `=iferror(mod(match(A8,flatten(Sheet2!$A$3:$E$5),0),COLUMNS(Sheet2!A3:E5)))` in determine the group in which every name belongs to. You can hide this helper cells
2. Use the following conditional formula: `=countif($C$4:$D$8,C4)>1` to count the number of people that share a similar skill, and colorize the cell if there is more than one from the same skill group

[image]

Comment: Should i also be mirroring the formulas found on Sheet2 that you don't have displayed here?

Comment: no, no need for these. I forgot to delete them

Comment: I'm getting false positives when I try this on my production sheet.  The layout has multiple groups in close proximity and the lists are quite extensive.  It ranges all the way from A to BH.  When I try this, I get numbers somewhere in the 40s when there are no overlapping names in the groups, but only at specific rows.  It's not consistent.

Take a look at my example sheet.  I've updated it to reflect the layout of my current production sheet more closely.

Comment: I actually think I'm misunderstanding how this works, that number that is represented is the number of column it's under, so as long as no duplicate number is found, it should work.

Comment: you must update the formula to include the entire range. Also, you must create helper cells (C4:D8) in the screenshot for each of the groups on Sheet1

Comment: yea I got it working, but I also had to add $ for the "columns(Sheet2!$A$3:$E$5) part or else it was expanding to non existing cells.  other than that, it works perfectly.  Bit of an undertaking for my setup but it works and thats all I care about.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: nice. Please mark the question as answered :)